# Redirect after record deletion not working in Remix.run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, remix.run

I've got a simple Remix route for deleting a record that just has an action that redirects after deleting the record. I'm getting this weird problem where the redirect is not working for some reason, even though the record is getting deleted successfully. It stays on the current URL and tries to render a non-existent component, resulting in an application error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `RemixRoute`.
...
```

I can see the POST coming through to this action. I see the delete taking place. But then it seems to just ignore the redirect. Thanks for any insights you might have. Here is the code:

```
import { ActionArgs, redirect } from "@remix-run/node";
import { requireAuthor } from "~/session.server";
import invariant from "tiny-invariant";
import { deletePost } from "~/models/blog.server";

export async function action({ request, params }: ActionArgs) {
  await requireAuthor(request);
  invariant(params.slug, "slug not found");
  await deletePost({ slug: params.slug });
  return redirect('/blog');
}
```

Comment: The code looks correct, and I've never seen that error before. What does the POST response look like in your network tab? It should be status 204 with `x-remix-redirect: /blog` header.

Comment: Thanks @Kiliman. I'm not sure why this was happening, but I was able to fix it by moving the delete action to the $slug.tsx route instead of $slug.delete.tsx. For some reason, it didn't like the trailing folder on the url.